# How can I find the size of a const declared array in C?

Tags: c, arrays

In file1.c, I have the array

```
const uint8 myArray[] =
{
    0x4b, 0x28, 0x05, 0xbf,   
    ...
    0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff
};
```

In file2.c, I need to use the array as follows:

```
uint8* buffer = myArray;
uint32 length = ???
```

I've tried `length = sizeof(myArray)`, but this results in the following error:
`error: invalid application of ‘sizeof’ to incomplete type ‘const uint8[] {aka const unsigned char[]}’`.
Since it is constant, I could physically count the number of entries, but I need to do it programmatically because this constant is likely to change further on in development.

Comment: use a `#define` for the size of the array....`#define ARRAY_SIZE x` then `const uint8 myArray[ARRAY_SIZE] = { ... };`

Comment: It's probably an incomplete type because you're just picking up a *declaration* of the array (through a header file you haven't shown here) rather than the *definition* of the array. If you create a `const` `myArrayLength` in `file1.c`, you should be able to use `sizeof` there.

Comment: The definition of `myArray` is not visible in `file2.c`. Only the declaration is (though it seems you left that out in your question?), so you cannot get the size.

Answer (score 4):

In `file1.c`, export the length:

```
const size_t myArrayLength = sizeof(myArray);
```

And then add a declaration somewhere (in a header file for `file1.c` or maybe directly in `file2.c`) like:

```
extern const size_t myArrayLength;
```